# how to compare one value against 2 values in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I want to compare a a value against 2 values without using OR or DECODE. The value I want to compare with two values is the one which I am getting as a return code of a function. If I use OR or DECODE then I have to call function twice and it gives performance hit. Currently I am coding as below

```
select *
from table1 t1, table2 t1
where t1.empid = t2.empid
and myfunction(t2.balance) = t1.total OR myfunction(t2.balance) = -1
```

Please suggest if there is a way to call function once and compare with 2 values.

Comment: If the function is `deterministic` (and that is explicitly stated in the function definition), then it will be evaluated only once, even if it appears twice in the code. The `IN` solution is clearer, easier to maintain, but it may not have any performance advantage over `OR` (indeed, the optimizer will expand the `IN` condition to the `OR` condition!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To shorten your code you could use `IN` operator which acts like `OR`.

```
select *
from table1 t1
join table2 t1 on
  t1.empid = t2.empid
and myfunction(t2.balance) in (t1.total, -1)
```

I've also replaced old-fashioned join syntax in where clause for `JOIN` keyword and you're advised to be using that in your future SQL journeys.

Good thing to know would be that even though you call the function twice, most modern databases would actually call it only once, so I wouldn't be that much concerned about it.

Comment: Thanks a lot..!! I couldn't think of IN